How to store references that don't outlive its container
I want to store references that don't outlive its container (internally, those references are stored as pointers). Those references are not necessarily set when the container is constructed.
Take this code:
#[repr(C)]
struct Array {
    size: usize,
    arr: *mut Array,
}
// Drop for Array deallocates array recursively

// must have same representation as Array
#[repr(C)]
struct ShallowArray<'a> {
    inner: std::mem::ManuallyDrop<Array>,
    _phantom: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a Array>,
}
impl<'a> ShallowArray<'a> {
    fn new(size: usize) -> Self {
        let layout = Layout::array::<Array>(size).unwrap();
        let arr = unsafe { alloc::alloc(layout) } as *mut Array;
        unsafe {
            std::ptr::write_bytes(arr, 0, layout.size());
        }
        Self {
            inner: std::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(Array { size, arr }),
            _phantom: std::marker::PhantomData,
        }
    }
    fn set_i(&'a mut self, idx: usize, obj: &'a Array) {
        if idx >= self.inner.size {
            panic!("Index out of bounds");
        }
        unsafe {
            *self.inner.arr.add(idx) = Array {
                size: obj.size,
                arr: obj.arr,
            };
        }
    }
}
impl Drop for ShallowArray<'_> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // deallocate only the first level
        let layout = Layout::array::<Array>(self.inner.size).unwrap();
        unsafe { alloc::dealloc(self.inner.arr as *mut u8, layout) };
    }
}
fn test() {
    let arr1 = Array {
        size: 0,
        arr: std::ptr::null_mut(),
    };
    let mut arr = ShallowArray::new(3);
    // reverse order of previous declarations is problematic for
    // another reason
    arr.set_i(0, &arr1);
}

this fails with:
error[E0597]: `arr` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:58:5
   |
57 |     let mut arr = ShallowArray::new(3);
   |         ------- binding `arr` declared here
58 |     arr.set_i(0, &arr1);
   |     ^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
59 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `arr` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `arr` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `shallow::ShallowArray`


You are are not keeping a pointer to the obj being passed in (at least not as far as 'a describes) - you are copying it, so a lifetime doesn't seem to make sense.

@kmdreko I'm keeping a copy of the pointer it has, the for which will be valid only until it's dropped. So the container cannot last longer than the references it's passed

Ok, I think I see what you're going for. In that case just remove 'a from &'a mut self.

@kmdreko it improves things a bit, but this still doesn't build

Solution
as @kmdreko commented
just change &'a mut self to &mut self in set_i definition
Explanation
it happens since implementing Drop make the compiler call Drop::drop when the value goes out of scope
and

&'a self: means to borrow for a specified lifetime.
&self: means to borrow for just the scope of the function.

Consider following example,
struct MyStruct<'a>{
    my_ref : &'a i32,
}
impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    pub fn my_method(&'a mut self, my_arg: &'a i32) {
        todo!()
    }
}
impl<'a> Drop for MyStruct<'a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        todo!()
    }
}
fn main () {
    let my_i32 = 0;
    let mut my_instance = MyStruct {my_ref: &my_i32}; 
    //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // 'a start here, 'a is the life time of my_instance
    // from declare to out of scope (or dropped)

    my_instance.my_method(&my_i32);                         
    // and then we borrow my_instance for 'a as specified in function definition
    // that means the borrow is not done until my_instance is dropped
    
    // but since we implemented Drop for MyStruct
    // that means we call drop() when out of scope implicitly
    drop(my_instance)
    // and drop() take ownership
    // but you cannot take ownership, since it is still borrowed by my_method()
    // we need to wait until end of life of my_instance
    // that mean we need to call drop()
    // but we cannot call drop . . . so we entered infinte loop
}


thanks, but my example doesn't build even with the shorter borrow of self

OK it works if I swap the order and create the container last which sort of makes sense although in this case the Drop implementation doesn't touch freed memory.
